# type hashing password in joomla for my api

Tags: php, joomla, lumen

I am creating API for my Joomla with Lumen(Laravel)

Now for register user and login I need hashing password but I don't know what's type hashing in Joomla

I try `md5` but password after hashing is like this :

```
81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
```

and not like Joomla  password . Joomla password is like:

```
 $2y$10$iTYx.GJGVWiAYbwJ0ogsYe7KJwbn25aUCTNGolkrRvL8K4kvbqage
```

Other sample password Joomla :

```
$2y$10$8jNtsYNWJxBr0PmdZXzol.QFssGNH.O5bKuBuVB24Jk7nN0U8Q682
```

How can I find type hashing Joomla?

Has anyone ever done something like this?

My Joomla information:

```
Joomla! 3.8.4 Stable [ Amani ] 30-January-2018 15:00 GMT
Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Don't use Md5! it's not secure at all anymore! use either SHA or Bcrypt! to prove my point, you can copy and paste that hash into any md5 decryptor and it will get converted into plain text in next to no time

Comment: capitalisation, English, formatting.

Comment: @Isaac SHA* is also not secure for password verifiers. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Password hashing required a method that take CPU time (around 100ms) and requiring substantial memory (such as Argon2i) helps against GPU crackers.

Comment: @Isaac You mis-understand MD5 decryptors, they look up known passwords, they do not reverse the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla Uses the bcrypt password hashing algorithm to store the password. You can check the hashPassword method from UserHelper class.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.8.12/libraries/src/User/UserHelper.php

PS if you are creating REST API with Joomla then you can check the com_api extension which may help you to build up API's.

https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api